# Microsoft MSAL React SPA, and RESTful Django API

Tags: python, django, azure, single-sign-on

I don't know why I can't find confirmation in the docs, maybe I am not navigating them correctly, although MSAL seems to have options to fit it into any application. This is my first time integrating a SAML sso procedure into any of my web-apps. I am just looking for some clarity on the correct, and secure way to verify the person attempting to login, is actually logged in with the IDP.

I am confused at the part after confirmation of login is given to my redirect API, I currently have it all happening on the front-end, then submitting the response to my back-end. Which is a RESTful API built with Django, and postgres database. At this point, I am thinking I need to verify my accessToken for authenticity, but I am unsure if I should be creating another PublicClient instance in python, and then sending the same commands to the IDP.

To guess at this point, I'm thinking this is wrong, as I need to verify the token, rather than get another Access and Refresh token. I'm thinking I just need to verify there is a session open with the IDP, and that the Access Token matches. Can anyone shed some light on this, possibly provide even just some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client Python Django Web App uses the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to sign-in and obtain an Access Token from Azure AD.
The access token is used as a bearer token to authorize the user to call the Python Flask Web API protected by Azure AD.
The Python Flask Web API then receives a token for Azure Resource Management API using the On-Behalf-Of flow.

To learn more about handing access token validation at the API layer, look into this sample walkthrough: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-on-behalf-of#about-the-code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens